# Retrieve session value from Script 2 which is set in Script 1. PHP

Tags: php, session

I have a script 1 that does import on CSV files. There I set the following code:

```
$_SESSION['import_progress'] = $importedSoFar; //integer
```

then I have an ajax call that executes every **3** seconds to retrieve the value of this session:

```
public function importprogress() {
  if (isset($_SESSION['import_progress'])) {
       echo $_SESSION['import_progress'];
  }
}
```

but on the second script on function **importprogress** I do not have access to that session variable. Is it possible to make that variable accessible while the **script 1** is still running (importing)?

**Note:** session_start(); is already called on header file that is included before each file or script. so this is not the problem.

Comment: Is there a typo? `$_SESSION['imported_progress']` should not it be `$_SESSION['import_progress']`?

Comment: @Dachi yes thank you. fixed. but that was not the problem it was just my typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

try adding  `<?php session_start(); ?>` to the top of the page

Comment: session_start() is used in header file that is included on all pages and all scripts so that is not the problem.

Comment: under importprogress() function shouldn't the session be named import_progress not imported_progess like the original?

Comment: fixed it. it was my typo posting here